css transition property does not work when setting state using mousenter event
I want to show an animated text next to the button upon hovering the button. This works fine when I am using click event on button but doesn't work when using mouseenter and mouseleave events.
I'm animating using CSS transition -
#text-container {
  transition: max-width 3s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

App.tsx file -
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const TextComponent = () => {
  const [maxWidth, setMaxWidth] = useState('0vw');

  useEffect(() => {
    setMaxWidth('100vw');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="text-container" style={{ maxWidth, paddingLeft: '8px' }}>
      <div style={{ textWrap: 'nowrap' }}>Sample text??</div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        width: '300px',
      }}
    >
      <button
        onClick={() => setShow((prevShow) => !prevShow)}
        // onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)}
        // onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        Show Text
      </button>

      {show ? <TextComponent /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

StackBlitz - link

@Chintan, please don't submit meaningless edits.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-osndza?file=src%2FApp.tsx
When using these events how React handles component re-renders with the mouseenter and mouseleave events, React adds/removes the TextComponent, causing the CSS transition to restart each time.
I have checked in StackBlitz working fine
CSS (App.css)
#text-container {
  max-width: 0;
  transition: max-width 0.5s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#text-container.show {
  max-width: 100vw;
  transition: max-width 3s ease;
}

App.tsx
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const TextComponent = ({ show }) => (
  <div id="text-container" className={show ? 'show' : ''}>
    <div>Sample text??</div>
  </div>
);

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        width: '300px',
      }}
    >
      <button
        onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        Show Text
      </button>
      <TextComponent show={show} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Explanation:

The show state now toggles a CSS class (show) on #text-container.
CSS handles the max-width transition smoothly, even when the component is always rendered, preventing re-renders from disrupting the animation.

Solution 2:
To avoid always mounting TextComponent, you can use CSS transitions with inline styles but conditionally render the component only when the transition ends.
CSS (App.css)
#text-container {
  max-width: 0;
  transition: max-width 3s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#text-container.show {
  max-width: 100vw;
}

App.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const TextComponent = ({ show, onTransitionEnd }) => (
  <div
    id="text-container"
    className={show ? 'show' : ''}
    onTransitionEnd={onTransitionEnd}
  >
    <div>Sample text??</div>
  </div>
);

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) setIsMounted(true);
  }, [show]);

  const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
    if (!show) setIsMounted(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        width: '300px',
      }}
    >
      <button
        onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}
      >
        Show Text
      </button>
      {isMounted && (
        <TextComponent show={show} onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Explanation

isMounted controls whether TextComponent is in the DOM.
show triggers the transition, and onTransitionEnd removes TextComponent from the DOM only after the exit transition completes.


Agree with @Yogi. Also, this will always keep TextComponent mounted. We don't want to render it when show is false.

Click works because it keeps TextComponent rendered as long as show is true, so the transition has time to complete. With mouseenter/mouseleave, the component is added and removed quickly, causing the transition to reset before it can fully animate.

added another solution you can check
